# What to do if OP requests far more than just answering the question?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, accepted-answer, help-vampire

Being a newbie here in StackOverflow, I've been a user for time enough to be aware that SO is more about questions and answers than about users.

I'm a little bit upset today because, after giving an answer (correct btw) and investing some time in providing more information than just a yes or no, I've been pushed by the OP to continue discussion about it in chat.

I'm not so naive that I were not aware of how that was going to end and how it eventually ended: after being asked for things unrelated to the first question, I've been asked to review some unrelated code and to connect remotely to review the code myself (of course I declined).

Finally the answer wasn't accepted because I refused to do the OP’s work. I have to admit I was too much eager for the rep points and I let it go too far...

I suppose that's something not new... and that's the reason for my opening statement about questions and users. Downvote the question (that was upvoted before for unclear reasons, being not of general interest...) doesn't seem sensible, but I can't downvote the user for unfair behavior.

Ok, I can't downvote the user. Lesson learnt. But how do you cope with things like that?

Comment: Can't blame you for trying to be helpful, but I think you made the right choice there. Sometimes you come across lazy OPs like that. Just move on -- you answered the posted question, you were nice and explained some more, and if you're right you'll get upvoted by the community. Not much you could (or should) worry about beyond that. You aren't OP's employee.

Comment: Just walk away. Go into radio silence.